# Monitor Windows Processes for excessive memory usage

Tags: c#, .net, windows, process

What im trying to do is continuously monitor all windows processes for Memory and CPU Usage,if   a certain process exceeds a limit,i should be able to terminate it(provided that this app runs with admin rights) i have the following code

```
private PerformanceCounter theMemCounter = new PerformanceCounter(
    "Hyper-v Dynamic Memory VM",
    "Physical Memory",
    Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName);
```

But this is for a single process and i should know the process by name,Can you please guide me on this.

Comment: Killing a process when it uses the most resources is the best way to ensure that the damage you'll do to the data it is producing is optimally unrecoverable.  Especially effective on a busy dbase engine service.

Comment: @HansPassant i did not get you,are you saying its good?

Comment: can you tell the reason for downvoting?

Comment: @techno I think most people don't like the idea of terminating random processes.

Answer (score 2):

`Process.GetCurrentProcess` only refers to your program. Try `Process.GetProcesses()` to retrieve all processes currently running on the machine.

Comment: Can you elaborate am asking for monitoring

Comment: Not sure what you're asking for. `GetProcesses` will return an array of `Process` instances describing the processes currently running on your computer. These instances provide a wealth of information, including memory usage. They also provide methods to kill or otherwise interact with the processes.
I suggest you take a look at [the Process class documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Here's some quick code to know how much private memory exists per process:

```
        foreach (var process in Process.GetProcesses().OrderByDescending(process => process.PrivateMemorySize64))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(process.ProcessName + ": " + process.PrivateMemorySize64 + " bytes");
        }
```

Though, please listen to [Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant), he's right. Killing processes indiscriminately is not a great idea. If you are worried about something taking up a lot of memory, see if the manufacturer has a way to limit it (like SQL Server) or, if it's your own code, FIX IT.

Comment: Thanks is there a way to reduce process priority rather than killing it

Comment: Absolutely there is. `process.PriorityClass` is a read/write property which takes a `ProcessPriorityClass` enumeration value: `Idle`, `BelowNormal`, `Normal`, `AboveNormal`, `High`, and `RealTime`. You might want `BelowNormal`.

Comment: Thanks Jesse,my question is getting downvoted i have voted to close it,can you help me improve the question or help me close it.